# Select max and min values at the same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL table with the columns: ID, ADate, XValue and Type. For each "Type" value, I'd like to retrieve the most recent row (per ADate), the least recent row (per ADate) and also the row containing the highest "XValue" value.

Is it possible to be performed through a single SQL query? I've tried a few times with no success.

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using? Also when you say "register" do you mean "row"?

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Yeah, register I meant row. Sorry about that.

Comment: sounds possible. Can you post sample data and a query which you ve tried?

Comment: Why do you need it all at once, for god's sake?! That's totally possible, but solutions are going to look as horrible Frankensteins - basically, they are, as you can see from existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ID, ADate, XValue,[Type]
from (
  select *
     ,row_number() over (partition by type order by adate asc) AS DateSeq
     ,row_number() over (partition by type) AS TypeCount
     ,row_number() over (partition by type order by xvalue desc) AS ValueSeq
  from t
  ) as tt
where tt.DateSeq=1 OR tt.DateSeq=tt.TypeCount OR tt.ValueSeq=1
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) you could do something like this:

```
select ID, ADate, XValue and Type
from (
  select *
    , min_adate  = row_number() over (partition by type order by adate asc)
    , max_adate  = row_number() over (partition by type order by adate desc)
    , max_xvalue = row_number() over (partition by type order by xvalue desc)
  from t
  ) as sub
where 1 in (min_adate,max_adate,max_xvalue)
/* --also could be written as 
where min_adate = 1
   or max_adate = 1
   or max_xvalue = 1
*/
```

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) may make it more readable.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , min_adate  = row_number() over (partition by type order by adate asc)
    , max_adate  = row_number() over (partition by type order by adate desc)
    , max_xvalue = row_number() over (partition by type order by xvalue desc)
  from t
)
select ID, ADate, XValue and Type
from cte
where 1 in (min_adate,max_adate,max_xvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by aDate desc) as seqnum_adate_desc,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by aDate asc) as seqnum_adate_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by XValue desc) as seqnum_xvalue_desc
      from t
     ) t
where 1 in (seqnum_adate_desc, seqnum_adate_asc, seqnum_xvalue_desc);
```